# How to get currency according to country code in Android?

Tags: java, android, location, currency

In below code I can get country code (2 alpha). Is it possible to get currency according to the country code? If yes please tell me how? I don't want to add any runtime permission for this app.

```
final TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
final String simCountry = tm.getSimCountryIso();
if (simCountry != null && simCountry.length() == 2) { // SIM country code is available
    String country_code = simCountry.toLowerCase(Locale.US);
    //return result - "in". (for India)
    //here I want to get the currency according to the country code
}
```

Comment: You can use Java [java.util.Currency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Currency.html) class `Currency.getInstance(Locale.US).getCurrencyCode()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use ([Locale](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) And [Currency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Currency.html)) classes to find currency code.

Like:

```
final TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
final String simCountry = tm.getSimCountryIso();
if (simCountry != null && simCountry.length() == 2) { 
    String country_code = simCountry.toLowerCase(Locale.US);
    Currency.getInstance(new Locale("", country_code)).getCurrencyCode()
}


//  Currency.getInstance(new Locale("", "us")).getCurrencyCode() -- This Return USD
//  Currency.getInstance(new Locale("", "in")).getCurrencyCode() -- This Retrun INR
```